# Scope of Oracle package level variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

Given the following Oracle (10g) package definition:

```
create or replace PACKAGE "foo"
AS

   bar VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL;

END;
```

what is the scope of bar? Does each session get its own foo.bar, or is foo.bar global across sessions?

Can you quote me chapter and verse from a reference document?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The scope is at the session level.  See the first sentence under the heading "Added Functionality" in the [PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/packages.htm#i2408)

Comment: You can change this behaviour by setting: PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;

Comment: You're not trying to say the globals are available across sessions, are you? Here is a description from the Oracle Application Developers Guide of PRAGMA_SERIALLY_REUSABLE: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_pc.htm#1008314

Comment: Sorry, as usual, was not clear. It changes the scope of the package var from session to unit of work. Essentially disabling the reussability of the variable

Answer (score 1):

This variable can contain different values across multiple sessions. If you want to change this, please use PRAGMA_SERIALLY_REUSABLE.